# Emoji Position in UITextView different in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, emoji, textkit

I'm trying to get the lowest point y-coordinate of an Apple Emoji flag within my text view. I've tried a lot of approaches, so far this gives me the closest answer:

```
textView.text = @"\U0001f1fa\U0001f1f8"; // US Flag
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
CGPoint location = [textView.layoutManager locationForGlyphAtIndex:0];
```

This gives me a point on the bottom-left of the emoji. Both iOS 7 and iOS 8 return the same point, but the two systems lay out the emoji differently. On iOS 7, the lowest point of the flag (somewhere in the middle) is aligned with the y-coordinate of the returned point. On iOS 8, the bottom left corner pixel of the flag (not the lowest point) is actually on the returned point. So the iOS 7 flag is slightly higher than the iOS 8 flag. Is there a way to get the y-coordinate of the lowest point in an Apple Emoji flag on iOS 8? Could this be a UIKit bug?

iOS 7 screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89847056/iOS%207.png

iOS 8 screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89847056/iOS%208.png